# SQL : Find if table's 'A' ID exists to table's 'B' ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. Table A is `priceList` that contains 2 columns. **ID** and **currency_id** . Table B is `priceListItems` that contains 3 columns. **Product** **priceListID**  **ProductID**.

For Example `priceList`

| ID | CurrencyID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | DF10CCE |

And `priceListItems`

| ID | priceListID | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | DESK |

I would like to write a statement in SQL to return a boolean (0 or 1) if the `priceList` has Items in, comparing with  `priceListItems` based on their ID columns (For table A: ID , and for Table B: priceListID )

So if the `priceList's ID` exists in `priceListItems's priceListID`, the result should be true.

How i can achieve that?

Is the follwing correct?

```
SELECT priceList.id, 
       IF(priceListItems.id IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) as priceListItems
FROM priceList
LEFT JOIN priceListItems ON (priceList.id = priceListItems.id)
```

Comment: 'Im trying something like' - very good - what's the question?

Comment: Your current logic is correct.  What is the problem/question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the statement i wrote is correct in comparison to what im asking:)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution to the problem stated in the question is already given, and that makes this question no longer a question.

Comment: *Is the follwing correct?* Only when `priceListItems.priceListID` is defined as unique.

Comment: I retracted my close vote... (see answer from @P.Salmon)

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT id,
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM priceListItems
                WHERE priceList.id = priceListItems.priceListID )
FROM priceList;
```

Answer (score 0):

priceList.id = priceListItems.id this test is incorrect and should be priceList.id = priceListItems.pricelistid

and IF(priceListItems.id IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) is dubious surely if null then true makes more sense..

Answer (score 0):

The if() function can get the job nicely done. Assuming ID 4 from the pricelist has two rows in the pricelistitems and ID 5 from the pricelist has no entry in the pricelistitems, we can try:

```
insert priceList values(3,'DF10CCE'),(4,'DF11223'),(5,'DD11225');
insert priceListItems values(1,3,'desk'),(2,4,'pp'),(3,4,'ss');
select id, if((select count(*) from priceListItems where pricelistid=pl.id),1,0) from priceList pl;
```

The correlated subquery `(select count(*) from priceListItems where pricelistid=pl.id)` returns an int which is greater or equal to 0, which can be used directly as a boolean in the `if()` function to determine which value should be returned.